# inserting content into node using field

Tags: entities

I am really stuck and need some advice, I'd like to know how I can go about doing this, simply put:

A website contributor enters a value into a field which is placed into the html.

eg. I have say two fields that will determine an image name and the file type. In field 1 the user enters [ABC], in field 2 the user enters [123].

The output of this would be `<img http://www.example.com/[ABC].[123] />`

I have never worked with my own custom modules/fields etc before, a point in the right direction would be a big help.

Comment: This would be hard to do without writing some PHP. Would you be able to write a template file for the relevant content type?  if so, you can do it.

Comment: Thanks olyN, would you say that is the best way to go about this? I have simplified matters a great deal in the above example but hope if I can work out how to achieve the above then I should be able to do the rest.

Each field will be used multiple times on the node. Is a custom template file still the best way knowing this? I've not been able to find a definitive answer.

Comment: It would be fairly straightforward to do it that way. is the image URL eternal to the drupal site, as well? I'm adding some instructions in an answer below. :)

Comment: I have a group of fields: http://oi57.tinypic.com/wi0z8i.jpg

Each field will correspond to an element, some need to be incorporated into the html (like in my op example) some are fine as text fields.

The group of fields can be used multiple times in the article. This I already have in place.

Comment: It may help to understand it is a way of my contributors posting multipile images in a list style article (like buzz feed), but giving each image a title, source etc.

The added issue is that the images all live on an external server but they will all live in the same folder and have a unified file name. eg folder/image_01, folder/image_02 etc

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a template, 
1. create a file inside your /sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME folder, called node--CONTENT_TYPE.tpl.php.
2. copy the contents of node.tpl.php into that file.
3. add something like the following to the template file, where you want to print the image:

```
<img src="http://example.com/<?php 
    print $node->YOUR_FIELD_1[$node->language][0]['value'] . 
    '.' .
    $node->YOUR_FIELD_2[$node->language][0]['value']; 
    ?> 
 alt="..." ... >
```

Another possibility (probably better), would be to use the [filefield sources](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module, and let the users upload the image to your drupal site by pasting the url.

Comment: Thank you olyN, I am going to try this method in the hope I can get it to work. My main concern is that I have things set up to post multiple images and it looks like this way will work for one static image.

Comment: if you have more images, you'll have to loop through them. You can allow multiple values for a field, and/or use the multifield module, if you need to group together multiple fields into one group.